# Does Firebase messaging token change offline?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used Firebase messaging service in my andorid application which users can send notification to each other where a middle server manages users tokens. To keep tokens up to date I use the following method in **FirebaseMessagingService**:

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
       //Sending username and token to server
       // I check if user have active internet connection
       if (isOnline()){
             sendTokenToServer(token);
       }
}
```

In some cases users says that sending notification is failed and I noticed that the target TOKEN is not up to date. The only thing I am afraid is if Firebase Tokens might be refreshed when user is offline? What other reasons may cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some devices not able to handle API calls from the service, in that case, you may send the **token** to the **server** but your server not **receiving your token**. So I suggest you send Token from your activity using blew code.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I have to confirm this solution in some days. So how do I attach this activity method to the `onNewToken` method of Firebase service? Do you run this every time you need to work with user token?

Comment: I do not use the token from **FirebaseMessagingService **, rather I call the above code to get token inactivity and pass the token to the server via API call.  Although the token is not refreshed all the time I do call and send it to the server whenever I call Activity.

Comment: In my case if the target user not open the application (after a token refresh) other users still can not interact with him because has an outdated token on our server. In fact my question is if Firebase token changes without user interaction or even when user is offline?

Comment: Firebase token does not refresh always, rather firebase keeps one token after installation and provided that token alway unless the user uninstalls the app.  If your user installs your app and launch your app at least once that will enough for getting token.  If you use token from Activity, you can alwasys get token and send to server. If token changed that will update your server when user again open his/ her app.